# Incorrect behaviour git submodule

Tags: ios, git, github

I created a template project. I called it Test. I created repo on github. I found the RestKit.xcodeproj file inside of the cloned RestKit project directory and draged it into the Project Navigator.

```
cd Test
git init
git submodule add git://github.com/RestKit/RestKit.git
git add .
git add -u
git commit -m "first commit"
git push
```

Push was OK.

My Test project:

[image]

I decided to check github's repo. I do git clone. Clone was ok, but RestKit.xcodeproj appeared in red color.

Test project after cloning:

[image]

What is wrong ?

Comment: What does git status say on the command line for the new repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `clone` you need to `git submodule update -i`